# Obtain specific expectation value for a variational quantum circuit via optimization process

Tags: variational-quantum-algorithms

I have a quantum circuit built using CNOT gates and RY gates.
I would like to obtain a specific expectation value for an observable (e.g. $\langle Z \rangle$ of the third qubit equal to a constant C).

I thought of doing that by minimizing the cost function
$ L = (\langle Z \rangle - C)^2$
with an optimization process.

What is the best way to do it?

What I'm doing right now is this:

```python
def objective_function(params):    
    # Compute the expectation value of Z_3 for the trial state
    expectation_value = ansatz(params)
    
    # Use a cost function to penalize deviations from the target value
    cost = (expectation_value - target_expectation)**2
    
    return cost

target_expectation = 0.5

from scipy.optimize import minimize

num_params=P
initial_params = np.random.uniform(-3,3,num_params)  # Initial parameters for the quantum circuit
result = minimize(objective_function, initial_params, method='COBYLA')
```

But since I'm not an expert on variational quantum algorithms (and their optimizator) I would like to have some advice.